# asp-page tag helper inserts encoded url inside form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a razor page with two page handlers:

```
public IActionResult OnGetDisTest(int Id)
{            
    discussion = _service.GetDiscussion(Id, null);
    return Page();
}
public IActionResult OnGetDisTestThread( int Id)
{            
    discussion = _service.GetDiscussion(null, Id);

    return Page();
}
```

Accessing them with tag helpers in anchor tags works fine:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <a asp-page="/DisTest" asp-page-handler="DisTest" asp-route-Id=@RandomNumber()> Click for Random Discussion Test by Id</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <a asp-page="/DisTest" asp-page-handler="DisTestThread" asp-route-Id="38796"> Click for Discussion Test by ThreadId, No replies</a>
</div>
```

This generates html like...

```
<a href="/DisTest/773?handler=DisTest"> Click for Random Discussion Test by Id</a>
```

When trying to use this in a form (these are all on an MVC view page, outside of the razor page) like so:

```
<form asp-page="/DisTest" asp-page-handler="DisTestThread" method="get">
    <label>Enter thread Id</label>
    <input type="number" name="Id" />
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Show Discussion </button>
</form>
```

This is what it generates:

```
<form method="get" action="/?page=%2FDisTest&amp;handler=DisTestThread">
    <label>Enter thread Id</label>
    <input type="number" name="Id">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Show Discussion </button>
</form>
```

Which does not work. I've found many example of forms inside a razor using tag helpers but none linking TO a razor page. How?